# Migrating JFreeChart from Itext 5 to 7

Tags: java, itext, jfreechart, itext7

I am migrating my app from Itext 5 to 7 and cannot find anything on how to add a JFreeChart to my document. I asked on that forum but they could not help so they sent me here. Here is my working Itext 5 code:

```
PdfContentByte cb=writer.getDirectContent();
PdfTemplate tp=cb.createTemplate(sizeX*scale+1,sizeY*scale+1);
PdfGraphics2D g2d=new PdfGraphics2D(cb,sizeX*scale+1,sizeY*scale+1);
tp.setWidth(sizeX*scale+1);
tp.setHeight(sizeY*scale+1);
Chart.getInstance().getChart().draw(g2d, new java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Float(0,0,sizeX*scale,sizeY*scale));
g2d.dispose();
cb.add(tp);
```

Can someone help me create the itext 7 equivalent? TIA.

Comment: That is actually in our backlog, and it's assigned to me. Do not expect a date, it's been in the backlog since 01/Dec/16 3:14 PM and it'll probably be there a bit longer. Although, if there would be customer demand, that would increase the priority.

Comment: Are you saying the equivalent methods and objects do not yet exist?

Comment: I am saying that the example code in the book iText in Action has not yet been ported from iText 5 to iText 7. I didn't say anything about the iText code itself. There will definitely have been some refactoring, moving classes and methods around.

Comment: OK, so essentially there is no documentation yet to get me what I need, right?

Comment: Exactly, your code will probably work with some minor changes, but the documentation doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, iText has dropped the PdfGraphics2D class.  One approach you could try is to used [OrsonPDF](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsonpdf) for the `PDFGraphics2D` implementation (it will create a PDF version of your chart), then embed that in your PDF created by iText.  I wrote a blog post about that here:

https://jfree.github.io/orsonpdf/

Here is the source code (needs JFreeChart 1.5.0, OrsonPDF 1.7 or later, and iText 7 - I used 7.0.4):

```
package com.orsonpdf.demo;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.xobject.PdfFormXObject;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Image;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.orsonpdf.PDFDocument;
import com.orsonpdf.PDFGraphics2D;
import com.orsonpdf.Page;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.block.BlockBorder;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.title.TextTitle;
import org.jfree.chart.ui.HorizontalAlignment;
import org.jfree.data.time.Month;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;

/**
 * Creates a PDF document with iText, then inserts a PDF chart generated with
 * JFreeChart and OrsonPDF.
 */
public class ITextPDFWithChart {

    private static byte[] generateChartPDF() {
        // here we use OrsonPDF to generate PDF in a byte array
        PDFDocument doc = new PDFDocument();
        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(500, 335);
        Page page = doc.createPage(bounds);
        PDFGraphics2D g2 = page.getGraphics2D();
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(createDataset());
        chart.draw(g2, bounds);
        return doc.getPDFBytes();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a chart.
     *
     * @param dataset  a dataset.
     *
     * @return A chart.
     */
    private static JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset dataset) {

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
            "International Coffee Organisation : Coffee Prices",
            null, "US cents/lb", dataset);

        String fontName = "Serif";
        chart.getTitle().setFont(new Font(fontName, Font.BOLD, 18));
        chart.addSubtitle(new TextTitle(
                "Source: http://www.ico.org/historical/2010-19/PDF/HIST-PRICES.pdf", 
                new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, 14)));

        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setDomainPannable(true);
        plot.setRangePannable(false);
        plot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
        plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);
        plot.getDomainAxis().setLowerMargin(0.0);
        plot.getDomainAxis().setLabelFont(new Font(fontName, Font.BOLD, 14));
        plot.getDomainAxis().setTickLabelFont(new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, 10));
        plot.getRangeAxis().setLabelFont(new Font(fontName, Font.BOLD, 14));
        plot.getRangeAxis().setTickLabelFont(new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, 10));
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.GRAY);
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.GRAY);
        chart.getLegend().setItemFont(new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, 14));
        chart.getLegend().setFrame(BlockBorder.NONE);
        chart.getLegend().setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
        XYItemRenderer r = plot.getRenderer();
        if (r instanceof XYLineAndShapeRenderer) {
            XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) r;
            renderer.setDefaultShapesVisible(false);
            renderer.setDrawSeriesLineAsPath(true);
            // set the default stroke for all series
            renderer.setAutoPopulateSeriesStroke(false);
            renderer.setDefaultStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0f, 
                    BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL), false);
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.RED);
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, new Color(24, 123, 58));
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, new Color(149, 201, 136));
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(3, new Color(1, 62, 29));
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(4, new Color(81, 176, 86));
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(5, new Color(0, 55, 122));
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(6, new Color(0, 92, 165));
        }

        return chart;

    }

    /**
     * Creates a dataset, consisting of two series of monthly data.
     *
     * @return the dataset.
     */
    private static XYDataset createDataset() {

        TimeSeries s1 = new TimeSeries("Indicator Price");
        s1.add(new Month(1, 2010), 126.80);
        s1.add(new Month(2, 2010), 123.37);
        s1.add(new Month(3, 2010), 125.30);
        s1.add(new Month(4, 2010), 126.89);
        s1.add(new Month(5, 2010), 128.10);
        s1.add(new Month(6, 2010), 142.20);
        s1.add(new Month(7, 2010), 153.41);
        s1.add(new Month(8, 2010), 157.46);
        s1.add(new Month(9, 2010), 163.61);
        s1.add(new Month(10, 2010), 161.56);
        s1.add(new Month(11, 2010), 173.90);
        s1.add(new Month(12, 2010), 184.26);
        s1.add(new Month(1, 2011), 197.35);
        s1.add(new Month(2, 2011), 216.03);
        s1.add(new Month(3, 2011), 224.33);
        s1.add(new Month(4, 2011), 231.24);
        s1.add(new Month(5, 2011), 227.97);
        s1.add(new Month(6, 2011), 215.58);
        s1.add(new Month(7, 2011), 210.36);
        s1.add(new Month(8, 2011), 212.19);
        s1.add(new Month(9, 2011), 213.04);
        s1.add(new Month(10, 2011), 193.90);
        s1.add(new Month(11, 2011), 193.66);
        s1.add(new Month(12, 2011), 189.02);
        s1.add(new Month(1, 2012), 188.90);
        s1.add(new Month(2, 2012), 182.29);
        s1.add(new Month(3, 2012), 167.77);
        s1.add(new Month(4, 2012), 160.46);
        s1.add(new Month(5, 2012), 157.68);
        s1.add(new Month(6, 2012), 145.31);
        s1.add(new Month(7, 2012), 159.07);
        s1.add(new Month(8, 2012), 148.50);
        s1.add(new Month(9, 2012), 151.28);
        s1.add(new Month(10, 2012), 147.12);
        s1.add(new Month(11, 2012), 136.35);
        s1.add(new Month(12, 2012), 131.31);
        s1.add(new Month(1, 2013), 135.38);
        s1.add(new Month(2, 2013), 131.51);
        s1.add(new Month(3, 2013), 131.38);

        TimeSeries s2 = new TimeSeries("Columbian Milds");
        s2.add(new Month(1, 2010), 207.51);
        s2.add(new Month(2, 2010), 204.71);
        s2.add(new Month(3, 2010), 205.71);
        s2.add(new Month(4, 2010), 200.00);
        s2.add(new Month(5, 2010), 200.54);
        s2.add(new Month(6, 2010), 224.49);
        s2.add(new Month(7, 2010), 235.52);
        s2.add(new Month(8, 2010), 243.98);
        s2.add(new Month(9, 2010), 247.77);
        s2.add(new Month(10, 2010), 230.02);
        s2.add(new Month(11, 2010), 244.02);
        s2.add(new Month(12, 2010), 261.97);
        s2.add(new Month(1, 2011), 279.88);
        s2.add(new Month(2, 2011), 296.44);
        s2.add(new Month(3, 2011), 300.68);
        s2.add(new Month(4, 2011), 312.95);
        s2.add(new Month(5, 2011), 302.17);
        s2.add(new Month(6, 2011), 287.95);
        s2.add(new Month(7, 2011), 285.21);
        s2.add(new Month(8, 2011), 286.97);
        s2.add(new Month(9, 2011), 287.54);
        s2.add(new Month(10, 2011), 257.66);
        s2.add(new Month(11, 2011), 256.99);
        s2.add(new Month(12, 2011), 251.60);
        s2.add(new Month(1, 2012), 255.91);
        s2.add(new Month(2, 2012), 244.14);
        s2.add(new Month(3, 2012), 222.84);
        s2.add(new Month(4, 2012), 214.46);
        s2.add(new Month(5, 2012), 207.32);
        s2.add(new Month(6, 2012), 184.67);
        s2.add(new Month(7, 2012), 202.56);
        s2.add(new Month(8, 2012), 187.14);
        s2.add(new Month(9, 2012), 190.10);
        s2.add(new Month(10, 2012), 181.39);
        s2.add(new Month(11, 2012), 170.08);
        s2.add(new Month(12, 2012), 164.40);
        s2.add(new Month(1, 2013), 169.19);
        s2.add(new Month(2, 2013), 161.70);
        s2.add(new Month(3, 2013), 161.53);

        TimeSeries s3 = new TimeSeries("Other Milds");
        s3.add(new Month(1, 2010), 158.90);
        s3.add(new Month(2, 2010), 157.86);
        s3.add(new Month(3, 2010), 164.50);
        s3.add(new Month(4, 2010), 169.55);
        s3.add(new Month(5, 2010), 173.38);
        s3.add(new Month(6, 2010), 190.90);
        s3.add(new Month(7, 2010), 203.21);
        s3.add(new Month(8, 2010), 211.59);
        s3.add(new Month(9, 2010), 222.71);
        s3.add(new Month(10, 2010), 217.64);
        s3.add(new Month(11, 2010), 233.48);
        s3.add(new Month(12, 2010), 248.17);
        s3.add(new Month(1, 2011), 263.77);
        s3.add(new Month(2, 2011), 287.89);
        s3.add(new Month(3, 2011), 292.07);
        s3.add(new Month(4, 2011), 300.12);
        s3.add(new Month(5, 2011), 291.09);
        s3.add(new Month(6, 2011), 274.98);
        s3.add(new Month(7, 2011), 268.02);
        s3.add(new Month(8, 2011), 270.44);
        s3.add(new Month(9, 2011), 274.88);
        s3.add(new Month(10, 2011), 247.82);
        s3.add(new Month(11, 2011), 245.09);
        s3.add(new Month(12, 2011), 236.71);
        s3.add(new Month(1, 2012), 237.21);
        s3.add(new Month(2, 2012), 224.16);
        s3.add(new Month(3, 2012), 201.26);
        s3.add(new Month(4, 2012), 191.45);
        s3.add(new Month(5, 2012), 184.65);
        s3.add(new Month(6, 2012), 168.69);
        s3.add(new Month(7, 2012), 190.45);
        s3.add(new Month(8, 2012), 174.82);
        s3.add(new Month(9, 2012), 178.98);
        s3.add(new Month(10, 2012), 173.32);
        s3.add(new Month(11, 2012), 159.91);
        s3.add(new Month(12, 2012), 152.74);
        s3.add(new Month(1, 2013), 157.29);
        s3.add(new Month(2, 2013), 149.46);
        s3.add(new Month(3, 2013), 149.78);

        TimeSeries s4 = new TimeSeries("Brazilian Naturals");
        s4.add(new Month(1, 2010), 131.67);
        s4.add(new Month(2, 2010), 124.57);
        s4.add(new Month(3, 2010), 126.21);
        s4.add(new Month(4, 2010), 126.07);
        s4.add(new Month(5, 2010), 127.45);
        s4.add(new Month(6, 2010), 143.20);
        s4.add(new Month(7, 2010), 156.87);
        s4.add(new Month(8, 2010), 163.21);
        s4.add(new Month(9, 2010), 175.15);
        s4.add(new Month(10, 2010), 175.38);
        s4.add(new Month(11, 2010), 190.62);
        s4.add(new Month(12, 2010), 204.25);
        s4.add(new Month(1, 2011), 219.77);
        s4.add(new Month(2, 2011), 247.00);
        s4.add(new Month(3, 2011), 260.98);
        s4.add(new Month(4, 2011), 273.40);
        s4.add(new Month(5, 2011), 268.66);
        s4.add(new Month(6, 2011), 250.59);
        s4.add(new Month(7, 2011), 245.69);
        s4.add(new Month(8, 2011), 249.83);
        s4.add(new Month(9, 2011), 255.64);
        s4.add(new Month(10, 2011), 234.28);
        s4.add(new Month(11, 2011), 236.75);
        s4.add(new Month(12, 2011), 228.79);
        s4.add(new Month(1, 2012), 228.21);
        s4.add(new Month(2, 2012), 215.40);
        s4.add(new Month(3, 2012), 192.03);
        s4.add(new Month(4, 2012), 180.90);
        s4.add(new Month(5, 2012), 174.17);
        s4.add(new Month(6, 2012), 156.17);
        s4.add(new Month(7, 2012), 175.98);
        s4.add(new Month(8, 2012), 160.05);
        s4.add(new Month(9, 2012), 166.53);
        s4.add(new Month(10, 2012), 161.20);
        s4.add(new Month(11, 2012), 148.25);
        s4.add(new Month(12, 2012), 140.69);
        s4.add(new Month(1, 2013), 145.17);
        s4.add(new Month(2, 2013), 136.63);
        s4.add(new Month(3, 2013), 133.61);

        TimeSeries s5 = new TimeSeries("Robustas");
        s5.add(new Month(1, 2010), 69.92);
        s5.add(new Month(2, 2010), 67.88);
        s5.add(new Month(3, 2010), 67.25);
        s5.add(new Month(4, 2010), 71.59);
        s5.add(new Month(5, 2010), 70.70);
        s5.add(new Month(6, 2010), 76.92);
        s5.add(new Month(7, 2010), 85.27);
        s5.add(new Month(8, 2010), 82.68);
        s5.add(new Month(9, 2010), 81.28);
        s5.add(new Month(10, 2010), 85.27);
        s5.add(new Month(11, 2010), 92.04);
        s5.add(new Month(12, 2010), 94.09);
        s5.add(new Month(1, 2011), 101.09);
        s5.add(new Month(2, 2011), 109.35);
        s5.add(new Month(3, 2011), 118.13);
        s5.add(new Month(4, 2011), 117.37);
        s5.add(new Month(5, 2011), 121.98);
        s5.add(new Month(6, 2011), 117.95);
        s5.add(new Month(7, 2011), 112.73);
        s5.add(new Month(8, 2011), 112.07);
        s5.add(new Month(9, 2011), 106.06);
        s5.add(new Month(10, 2011), 98.10);
        s5.add(new Month(11, 2011), 97.24);
        s5.add(new Month(12, 2011), 98.41);
        s5.add(new Month(1, 2012), 96.72);
        s5.add(new Month(2, 2012), 101.93);
        s5.add(new Month(3, 2012), 103.57);
        s5.add(new Month(4, 2012), 101.80);
        s5.add(new Month(5, 2012), 106.88);
        s5.add(new Month(6, 2012), 105.70);
        s5.add(new Month(7, 2012), 107.06);
        s5.add(new Month(8, 2012), 106.52);
        s5.add(new Month(9, 2012), 104.95);
        s5.add(new Month(10, 2012), 104.47);
        s5.add(new Month(11, 2012), 97.67);
        s5.add(new Month(12, 2012), 96.59);
        s5.add(new Month(1, 2013), 99.69);
        s5.add(new Month(2, 2013), 104.03);
        s5.add(new Month(3, 2013), 106.26);

        TimeSeries s6 = new TimeSeries("Futures (London)");
        s6.add(new Month(1, 2010), 62.66);
        s6.add(new Month(2, 2010), 60.37);
        s6.add(new Month(3, 2010), 58.64);
        s6.add(new Month(4, 2010), 62.21);
        s6.add(new Month(5, 2010), 62.46);
        s6.add(new Month(6, 2010), 69.72);
        s6.add(new Month(7, 2010), 78.17);
        s6.add(new Month(8, 2010), 78.42);
        s6.add(new Month(9, 2010), 75.87);
        s6.add(new Month(10, 2010), 80.08);
        s6.add(new Month(11, 2010), 86.40);
        s6.add(new Month(12, 2010), 88.70);
        s6.add(new Month(1, 2011), 96.02);
        s6.add(new Month(2, 2011), 104.53);
        s6.add(new Month(3, 2011), 111.36);
        s6.add(new Month(4, 2011), 111.34);
        s6.add(new Month(5, 2011), 116.76);
        s6.add(new Month(6, 2011), 110.51);
        s6.add(new Month(7, 2011), 103.36);
        s6.add(new Month(8, 2011), 102.71);
        s6.add(new Month(9, 2011), 96.10);
        s6.add(new Month(10, 2011), 88.64);
        s6.add(new Month(11, 2011), 85.78);
        s6.add(new Month(12, 2011), 87.65);
        s6.add(new Month(1, 2012), 84.19);
        s6.add(new Month(2, 2012), 88.69);
        s6.add(new Month(3, 2012), 91.37);
        s6.add(new Month(4, 2012), 91.81);
        s6.add(new Month(5, 2012), 96.82);
        s6.add(new Month(6, 2012), 94.75);
        s6.add(new Month(7, 2012), 96.14);
        s6.add(new Month(8, 2012), 96.12);
        s6.add(new Month(9, 2012), 94.65);
        s6.add(new Month(10, 2012), 94.66);
        s6.add(new Month(11, 2012), 87.32);
        s6.add(new Month(12, 2012), 85.94);
        s6.add(new Month(1, 2013), 88.85);
        s6.add(new Month(2, 2013), 94.41);
        s6.add(new Month(3, 2013), 97.22);

        TimeSeries s7 = new TimeSeries("Futures (New York)");
        s7.add(new Month(1, 2010), 142.76);
        s7.add(new Month(2, 2010), 134.35);
        s7.add(new Month(3, 2010), 134.97);
        s7.add(new Month(4, 2010), 135.12);
        s7.add(new Month(5, 2010), 135.81);
        s7.add(new Month(6, 2010), 152.36);
        s7.add(new Month(7, 2010), 165.23);
        s7.add(new Month(8, 2010), 175.10);
        s7.add(new Month(9, 2010), 187.80);
        s7.add(new Month(10, 2010), 190.43);
        s7.add(new Month(11, 2010), 206.92);
        s7.add(new Month(12, 2010), 221.51);
        s7.add(new Month(1, 2011), 238.05);
        s7.add(new Month(2, 2011), 261.41);
        s7.add(new Month(3, 2011), 274.10);
        s7.add(new Month(4, 2011), 285.58);
        s7.add(new Month(5, 2011), 277.72);
        s7.add(new Month(6, 2011), 262.52);
        s7.add(new Month(7, 2011), 255.90);
        s7.add(new Month(8, 2011), 260.39);
        s7.add(new Month(9, 2011), 261.39);
        s7.add(new Month(10, 2011), 236.74);
        s7.add(new Month(11, 2011), 235.25);
        s7.add(new Month(12, 2011), 227.23);
        s7.add(new Month(1, 2012), 227.50);
        s7.add(new Month(2, 2012), 212.09);
        s7.add(new Month(3, 2012), 188.78);
        s7.add(new Month(4, 2012), 181.75);
        s7.add(new Month(5, 2012), 176.50);
        s7.add(new Month(6, 2012), 159.93);
        s7.add(new Month(7, 2012), 183.20);
        s7.add(new Month(8, 2012), 169.77);
        s7.add(new Month(9, 2012), 175.36);
        s7.add(new Month(10, 2012), 170.43);
        s7.add(new Month(11, 2012), 155.72);
        s7.add(new Month(12, 2012), 149.58);
        s7.add(new Month(1, 2013), 154.28);
        s7.add(new Month(2, 2013), 144.89);
        s7.add(new Month(3, 2013), 141.43);

        TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(s1);
        dataset.addSeries(s2);
        dataset.addSeries(s3);        
        dataset.addSeries(s4);
        dataset.addSeries(s5);
        dataset.addSeries(s6);
        dataset.addSeries(s7);
        return dataset;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("ITextPDFWithChart.pdf");
        PdfDocument targetPDF = new PdfDocument(writer);
        Document document = new Document(targetPDF);
        document.add(new Paragraph("Demo showing a JFreeChart being rendered into a PDF document created by iText 7."));

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(generateChartPDF()));
        PdfDocument chartDoc = new PdfDocument(reader);
        PdfFormXObject chart = chartDoc.getFirstPage().copyAsFormXObject(targetPDF);
        Image chartImage = new Image(chart);
        document.add(new Paragraph("Here we add a chart... ").add(chartImage));
        document.close();
    }


}
```