# iText7: Can you use Graphics2D?

Tags: java, graphics2d, itext7

In iText5 it was possible to draw Graphics2D objects by starting like this

```
Rectangle rect = PageSize.A3.rotate();
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
Graphics2D g = cb.createGraphics(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
```

with "writer" being an instance of "PdfWriter".

PdfContentByte doesn't exist in iText7 and I haven't found a way to get Graphics2D involved yet. Is that still possible?

I'm fully aware that there's a canvas now that you can draw circles, rectangles, lines,... on but that would mean re-writing all of the existing code, so if you can still use Graphics2D somehow, it would be the prefered way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OrsonPDF` as the `Graphics2D` translator and embed the resulting PDF into a document created with `iText`.  An example with full instructions is given here:

https://jfree.github.io/orsonpdf/

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47593083/migrating-jfreechart-from-itext-5-to-7/47780461#47780461